Zfs on Linux: why my snapshot directory is empty?
I can recover a snapshot single file with this way
mount -t zfs rpool/ROOT/nas@snap1 /media/hd

then cd /media/hd and cp...
But some users said is possible to access snapshot without mount it
I try this
zfs set snapdir=visible rpool/ROOT/nas

Then I go to the directory and...
root@nas:~# ls /.
./    ../   .zfs/ 
root@nas:~# ls /.zfs/s
shares/   snapshot/ 
root@nas:~# ls /.zfs/s
shares/   snapshot/ 
root@nas:~# ls /.zfs/snapshot/snap1/
root@nas:~# find /.zfs/
/.zfs/
/.zfs/snapshot
/.zfs/snapshot/snap1
/.zfs/shares

Is empty!
Why?

Is rpool/ROOT/nas mounted on /?  You shouldn't need to set snapdir=visible. If you leave it as hidden, you can still access it if you know it's there.

Is that particular snapshot mounted elsewhere?

No, is not mounted
